# Custom Taxation

Tags: magento2, module, shipping, custom, tax

I am trying to figure out how to customize tax base on shipping information. If the customer is residing in US and the product will be shipped on US, the tax is 2%. However, if the customer is from US and he wanted to ship the product to UK, the tax is 1%. How should I implement this?

**Example:**

Shipping Locally (using local tax)

- US New York to US Michigan (2% tax)
- US Colorado to US California (2%
  tax) UK Wales to UK Britain (3% tax)
- UK Scotland to UK Britain (3%
  tax)

Shipping Internationally

- US New York to UK Britain (1% tax)
- US Colorado to UK Scotland (1% tax)

Answer (score 0):

1/ Go to Stores > Tax Zones & Rates > Create your Tax Rates

2/ Go to Stores > Tax Rules > Create your Tax Rules

3/ Go to the configuration section and set the tax to be calculated on shipping address:

Stores > Settings / Configuration > Sales / Tax > Calculation Settings > Tax Calculation Based On > Shipping Address

Comment: I am using magento 2 and I haven't found the tax configuration on your instructions. I think it is on Stores > Configuration Sales > Tax. To elaborate more about my question, if the shipping is local, local tax is used. e.g. US 2%, UK 3%, CA 4%. If the shipping is international it will be 1% US to UK 1%, UK to CA 1%. Something like that.

Comment: @xanderlopez I've updated my answer and also check this link for taxes setup https://www.fastcomet.com/tutorials/magento2/taxes